# Why am I losing my invocation context when testing code inside of a promise (angular + jasmine)

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, promise, q, angular-mock

I have simple controller where I want to test mechanics inside of a promise (in this case, I want to test that `foo` was called when I run `bar`.  Here's my controller:

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
  .controller('MyCtrl', function ($q) {

  var myPromise = $q.when();

  this.foo = function () {
    console.log('running foo');
  };

  this.bar = function () {
    myPromise.then(function () {
      this.foo();
    });
  };
});
```

And here's my jasmine test:

```
describe('MyCtrl', function () {
  var $controller, $scope, $q;

  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, _$q_, _$controller_) {
    $controller = _$controller_;
    $q = _$q_;
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
  }));

  describe('bar function', function () {
    it('should call the foo function', function () {
      var controller = $controller('MyCtrl', { $q: $q });
      spyOn(controller, 'foo');
      controller.bar();
      $scope.$digest();
      expect(controller.foo).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

When I run this test, I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'this.foo')
```

It seems that inside the `then()` function block, I lose invocation context referring to the controller.  When the test runs and hits `this.foo()`, `this` is undefined.

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but there might be a scoping issue. Try adding `var self = this` at the top of the controller, then changing the reference to `this.foo()` inside of the `this.bar()` function to `self.foo()`. Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'this' doesn't contain an attribute 'foo' because the context (to the outer scope) is not bound.

You could do one of the following:

1.

```
this.bar = function() {
    var that = this;
    myPromise.then(function () {
        that.foo();
    });
};
```

2.

```
this.bar = function() {
    function onSuccess() { this.foo(); }
    myPromise.then(onSuccess.bind(this));
};
```

Comment: Also, if you're able to use es6 syntax you can use an arrow function which preserves `this` from the outer context. `myPromise.then(() => this.foo());`.

Comment: binding to the outer scope was the answer.  The final code for my example looks like:
    myPromise.then(function () {
      this.foo();
    }.bind(this));